# make my own shell - C - chdir()

Tags: c, linux, shell, chdir

I have tried to write my own shell in C. I have a problem with `chdir()` function.
Sometimes I have an error message that says `execvp: No such file or Directory` and some others nothing. The directory is always the same. I am trying to reach a destination that exists.

```
if(strcmp(str,"exit\n")!=0){

    history_vector[i]=strdup(str);

    if(strcmp(str,"cd\n")==0){
        char *dir  = strtok(str," ");
        dir = strtok(NULL," ");
        if(chdir(dir) == -1) {
            perror("Cannot change directory"); 
        }   
        else {
            printf("Changing Directory .....\n"); 
        }
   }
```

Comment: Before calling the `chdir`, Have you check what is placed in that pointer.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? What is the value of `str`? What is the value of `dir`? What error do you get?

Comment: Oh, and if `cd` has an argument, the input string you need to compare to is ***not*** `"cd\n"`. Something you should have found very quickly if you just used a debugger, or just printed out the contents of `str`.

Answer (score 2):

The string comparison will never succeed if you expect there to be an argument.

The string `"cd\n"` which you're using with `strcmp()` doesn't include an argument, so it won't match if `str` is longer.

Comment: If you are unable to understand what's going on here, maybe writing a complicated shell application might be something you want to postpone, until your skills improve, somewhat. Either your string has an additional word, or it's not. There are no other possibilities. This is not a big mystery. If it's not, you have no additional words to extract here. If it does, your strcmp() is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
if(strncmp(str,"cd\n",2)==0)
```

in the 3rd line.. as you have to ignore white spaces .. to go inside if !!